# Using Scipy.optimize.curve_fit to fit an exponential

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

```
def Data_to_array(file):

    r = int
    x, y=[],[]
    data = []
    line_num = 0
    #call data

    P = open(file,'r')
    data = P.readlines()
    #Get it to ignore strings
    for line in data:
        line_num += 1
        if line.find("[data]") >= 0:
            r = (line_num+1)
            # Data = P.readlines()[:r]     
            # print (Data)
        if "Sampling Rate" in line:
            SR = float(line[15:])
       
        if "temperature=" in line:
            T = float(line[12:18])
            print(str("Temperature = ")) 
            print(T)
    Data = data[r:line_num] 

    #assign data into dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(Data)
    #rename column in data
    df = df.rename(columns = {0: 'volts'})
    #get it to recognise the index
    df.index.name = 'Index'
    #get it to recognise the data as number
    df = df.astype({'volts': float})
    #get index to start at 1
    df.index += 1
    #assign data to lists
    I = df.index.to_list()
    t = df['volts'].to_list()
    #get it to invert data
    y = [element * -1 for element in t]
    #multiply by sampling rate
    x = [element /(SR) for element in I]
    return x,y
#This is to create the exponential function
def Exponential_func(file):
    temp_array = Data_to_array(file)
    X = np.asarray(temp_array[0])
    a,b = float()
    #Y = temp_array[1]
    f = np.exp(a*X) + b
    return f

#This is to get the optomize function to work
def Exponential_model(file):
    temp_array = Data_to_array(file)
    X = np.asarray(temp_array[0])
    Y = np.asarray(temp_array[1])
    #f = np.exp(X)
    #exp_mod = lf.ExponentialModel(X,Y)
    #pars = exp_mod.guess(Y, X)
    r =     sp.optimize.curve_fit(X,Y,Exponential_func.f)
    return r
#This is to plot the data
def Plot_Data (file):
    temp_array = Data_to_array(file)
    X = np.asarray(temp_array[0])
    Y = np.asarray(temp_array[1])
    #p_0 = np.exp(X)
    #sp.optimize.curve_fit(X,Y,p_0)
    plt.scatter(X,Y)
    #plt.plot(Exponential_model.r)
    plt.show()
    plt.xlabel("Time (s)")
    plt.ylabel("Capacitence (μF)")
  # print(Data_to_array('Cz-Si-T-1.txt')[1])
Plot_Data("Cz-Si-T-82.txt")
Exponential_func("Cz-Si-T-82.txt")
Exponential_model("Cz-Si-T-82.txt")
```

When I try to use the sp.optomize function, I get the error "'function' object has no attribute 'f'" but when looking up this problem I have the function and variables in the correct order.
I need this piece of code to fit an exponential curve to my data, which does have an exp fit, can anyone help? It would also be helpful for the code to print the function of the fitted curve as I will be integrating under this later.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. First I'd like to mention that if you get an error message always post the trace back as well. Also try to make your example code complete, such that other can run it to reproduce your problem. In your case a minimalistic data set would be nice. That said, check the comment below.

Comment: I think there is a misconception on how `curve_fit` works. Your call to `f` is `class`-like but `Exponential_model` is a function. Actually this is ok as `curve_fit` need a function as input parameter. The function, however, should be of type `func( x, param1, param2, ...)` Yours is not. Hence, `X`, `a` and `b` should part the function call not the file name. It is not excluded to have a file name there, but not really within the concept. I suggest you look at some `curve_fit` examples first and try to modify your code accordingly. If you still have problems, come back. Cheers